# Returning a const char ** from a static const struct

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, literals

a.cpp:

```
static const struct A {
    int a1;
    const char ** a2;
} as[] = {
    {1,(const char *[]){"LOL",NULL}},
    {2,(const char *[]){"LOL","LOL2",NULL}}
};

const char ** getA(int a) {
    int i = 0;
    for(;i< sizeof(as)/sizeof(struct A);i++){
       if (as[i].a1 == a)
           return as[i].a2;
    }
}
```

Is there a context or scope problem in returning `const char **` from a static const struct initialized statically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is fine - compound literals that occur outside the body of a function have static storage duration.

Answer (score 2):

There's certainly no scope problem. Scope pertains to variables, not to values. (There is a problem with missing `{` in your code, though.)

Comment: +1, `{1,(const char *[])"LOL",NULL}},` should become `{1,(const char *[]){"LOL",NULL}},`.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to put a variable sized array of pointers into a fixed size struct. That can't be good.

Comment: that's not true. As long as he inserts the missing `{` it will work fine.